# retrieve McAfee Tray application about page through command line

Tags: batch-file, mcafee

I need to access the about page of the McAfee tray icon using a batch script. I have been trying to do this since a long time however, unable to make any progress.

Comment: Sometimes I'm really wondering which ideas non programmers have. It is not possible to get information displayed in a graphic window with pixels in an about dialog of a GUI application minimized to system tray from within command line interface as text. But all information displayed in McAfee about dialog are stored in Windows registry and can be read from there using appropriate batch code with `for`, `req query` and `set`.

Comment: Use free Process Monitor of Sysinternals (Microsoft) to find out which registry keys and values McAfee reads on opening the About dialog window to display the information you are interested in from command line.

Comment: thankyou i was able to retrieve it from the registry!